# concatenate specific columns on Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to add a multiples sets of data but  can't seem to make it work.

Say, I have three 3x9 dataframes

dfA:

|  | A: Wave height | A: Wave period | A: Wave dir | B: Wave height | B: Wave period | B: Wave dir | C: Wave height | C: Wave period | C: Wave dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 1.1 | 5 | 90 | 4.5 | 5 | 90 | 3.1 | 5 | 100 |
| 2/1/2001 | 1.2 | 4 | 91 | 4.7 | 5 | 98 | 3.0 | 5 | 101 |
| 3/1/2001 | 1.3 | 6 | 92 | 4.8 | 3 | 97 | 2.5 | 5 | 105 |

dfB:

|  | A: Wave height | A: Wave period | A: Wave dir | B: Wave height | B: Wave period | B: Wave dir | C: Wave height | C: Wave period | C: Wave dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/1/2001 | 4.1 | 5 | 290 | 4.5 | 5 | 290 | 3.1 | 5 | 300 |
| 4/1/2001 | 4.2 | 4 | 291 | 4.7 | 5 | 298 | 3.0 | 5 | 301 |
| 5/1/2001 | 4.3 | 6 | 292 | 4.8 | 3 | 297 | 2.5 | 5 | 305 |

dfC:

|  | A: Wave height | A: Wave period | A: Wave dir | B: Wave height | B: Wave period | B: Wave dir | C: Wave height | C: Wave period | C: Wave dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2001 | 1.1 | 5 | 190 | 5.5 | 5 | 290 | 6.1 | 5 | 104 |
| 3/1/2001 | 1.2 | 4 | 191 | 5.7 | 5 | 298 | 6.0 | 5 | 106 |
| 4/1/2001 | 1.3 | 6 | 192 | 5.8 | 3 | 297 | 6.5 | 5 | 103 |

You can see I have wave parameters at 3 locations: A, B, and C. I need to combine the wave parameters at **A from dfA**,**B from dfB**, then **C from dfC**.

So the result should be a 9x3 dataframe with this values:

|  | Wave height | Wave period | Wave dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 1.1 | 5 | 190 |
| 2/1/2001 | 1.2 | 4 | 191 |
| 3/1/2001 | 1.3 | 6 | 192 |
| 3/1/2001 | 4.5 | 5 | 290 |
| 4/1/2001 | 4.7 | 5 | 298 |
| 5/1/2001 | 4.8 | 3 | 297 |
| 2/1/2001 | 6.1 | 5 | 104 |
| 3/1/2001 | 6.0 | 5 | 106 |
| 4/1/2001 | 6.5 | 5 | 103 |

As you can see, some index will be duplicated so the results will have to be reindexed to 1/1/2001 to 9/1/2001 like this:

|  | Wave height | Wave period | Wave dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 1.1 | 5 | 190 |
| 2/1/2001 | 1.2 | 4 | 191 |
| 3/1/2001 | 1.3 | 6 | 192 |
| 4/1/2001 | 4.5 | 5 | 290 |
| 5/1/2001 | 4.7 | 5 | 298 |
| 6/1/2001 | 4.8 | 3 | 297 |
| 7/1/2001 | 6.1 | 5 | 104 |
| 8/1/2001 | 6.0 | 5 | 106 |
| 9/1/2001 | 6.5 | 5 | 103 |

I first tried plain concatenating but this encountered duplicate index error.
code:

```
pts = ('A','B','C')
  for pt in pts:
  df = 'df{}.format(pt)'
  new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=("Wave height","Wave period","Wave dir"))
  new_df["Wave Height"] = pd.concat([new_df["Wave height"], df['{}: Wave height'.format(pt)]])
  new_df["Wave period"] = pd.concat([new_df["Wave period"], df['{}: Wave period'.format(pt)]])
  new_df["Wave dir"] = pd.concat([new_df["Wave dir"], df['{}: Wave dir(pt)]])
```

I tried concatenating with ignore_index=True but then it only concatenates 1 column and replaces all with N/A.

I trying merge but it seems that it needs certain columns to match which is just as problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicated index values using pd.concat

But you can try with merge and parameter 'outer' :

```
pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on="name_of_colum_index", how="outer")
```

Set index name before.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split(': ')))
df = df.set_axis(idx, axis=1)

for name, d in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    print(f'level: {name}')
    print(d.droplevel(level=0, axis=1))
```

output:

```
level: A
          Wave height  Wave period  Wave dir
1/1/2001          1.1            5        90
2/1/2001          1.2            4        91
3/1/2001          1.3            6        92
3/1/2001          4.1            5       290
4/1/2001          4.2            4       291
5/1/2001          4.3            6       292
2/1/2001          1.1            5       190
3/1/2001          1.2            4       191
4/1/2001          1.3            6       192
level: B
          Wave height  Wave period  Wave dir
1/1/2001          4.5            5        90
2/1/2001          4.7            5        98
3/1/2001          4.8            3        97
3/1/2001          4.5            5       290
4/1/2001          4.7            5       298
5/1/2001          4.8            3       297
2/1/2001          5.5            5       290
3/1/2001          5.7            5       298
4/1/2001          5.8            3       297
level: C
          Wave height  Wave period  Wave dir
1/1/2001          3.1            5       100
2/1/2001          3.0            5       101
3/1/2001          2.5            5       105
3/1/2001          3.1            5       300
4/1/2001          3.0            5       301
5/1/2001          2.5            5       305
2/1/2001          6.1            5       104
3/1/2001          6.0            5       106
4/1/2001          6.5            5       103
```